# How to get element by xpath?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this xpath

```
//select[../..//text()[contains(., '22676')]]
```

and I want to get this element with javascript, how can I do this?  I want to do it through xpath because later that '22676' will be a variable

I read that you can do it with document.evaluate() but you have to pass a bunch of parameters which I don't know if I am doing it right or something is missing or if I have to put different parameters.

I also tried document._getElementsByXpath but when I try to do .lenght or something just to know I got it, it says 'undefined' 
anyway, does anyone knows a simpler and effective way to get it?

thank you for all your help, hope everyone is well during these times :)

Comment: What did you try, exactly? e.g., 
`xpathExpression = '//select[../..//text()[contains(., '22676')]]'`
`document.evaluate(xpathExpression)`

Comment: I tried what you said and it didn't work i put it like this 
ocument.evaluate("//select[../..//text()[contains(., '22676')]]",document) and it did, it returns the element I want, meaning it does find it, but I want to select a value from 0 to 2, how can I do that? I tried .selectedindex and options etc but it returns undefined do you know why?